# Memory Mapped File and Win Service - Cannot find File Created By Server

Tags: windows, service, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to create a memory mapped file with a windows service so it can hold a lot of static data that other windows applications can use.

My issue is that when I start the service - the service can read and write the memory mapped file easily. However, the windows apps cannot. They get a file not found error.

Using the same class to read and write the memory mapped file, in two windows applications I have no issues. So, I am under the belief that the use of the memory mapped files is correct but there is something else - probably in the realm of windows services that I am missing.

I have tried to add an access control but that does not help. Still, file not found.

Admittedly, I am not very experienced with windows services. I have tried to create simple files to write my exceptions into but they are not being created from the service either. As for the account, I am using my own windows account (I have limited, local admin privs).

I am not using the Network Services account because I need to access a database with credentials embedded in my user account.

Any ideas would be awesome because I have started to spin my wheels at this point.

Comment: Are you talking about an actual file or a memory-mapping object?  Show your code.

Comment: I've got an identical situation, did you ever get a solution or answer?

Comment: @nrjohnstone: consider asking your own question.  This one is too ambiguous to answer so yours shouldn't be considered a duplicate - at least so long as you include the details that are missing in this one!

Answer (score 3):

You might need to prepend the MMF name with @"Global\".  I believe the newer versions of Windows runs services under a different session than other apps.

I saw references to the following article: [Impact of Session 0 Isolation on Services and Drivers in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx)

You might also need to modify the Local Security Policy "Create global objects", depending on what user account you are running your windows app from.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing later on and it worked well for me

Comment: i have experienced a similar problem and this has resolved it for me.

Comment: An example of implementing the Local Security Policy can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345274/memory-mapped-file-access-denied