# Can't open memory mapped file from log-on screen

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to use memory mapped files to share data between a windows (written in C#) service and a screensaver written in C++.

While this works well if the screensaver is running in the context of a logged in user it doesn't work if the screensaver is running on the log-on screen. Instead `OpenFileMapping` fails with an unauthorized access error. It seems obvious that I'm missing an access rule (or system setting perhaps to make this work) but I can't figure out which one.

My c# side code:

```
    public CreateMemMappedFile(string fileName)
    {
        this.rootName = fileName;
        var security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();

        security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(
            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
            MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
        security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(
            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AnonymousSid, null),
            MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
        security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(
            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NullSid, null),
            MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

        // printing the SID from the screensaver shows that we are running as Local Service
        security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(
            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalServiceSid, null),
            MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

        this.handle = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(
            "Global\\" + fileName, 1024 * 1024,
            MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute
            ,MemoryMappedFileOptions.DelayAllocatePages,
            security, System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable
            );
    }
```

My screensaver code:

```
        TCHAR* myFileName = _T("Global\\myfile");
        ipcBufferHandle = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ,FALSE,myFileName);
        if(ipcBufferHandle == NULL)
        {
             _tprintf(_T("couldn't open file \"%s\" with error code %d\n"),myFileName,GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(_T("opened file %s\n"),myFileName);
        }
```

which outputs `couldn't open file "Global\myfile" with error code 5`

Comment: What are you communicating over the memory mapped file, perhaps there may be another form of IPC that may work better.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm moving uncompressed video. Using memory mapped files gives me a path for graceful degradation, whereas sockets require explicit handling of the case where the screensaver can't keep up.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [msdn OpenFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is defined as

```
HANDLE WINAPI OpenFileMapping(
  _In_  DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
  _In_  BOOL bInheritHandle,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpName
);
```

So when you call `bInheritHandle` with `FALSE`, the handle isn't shared with other processes. Try `TRUE`, just like you did in C# with `System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable`.

```
ipcBufferHandle = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, TRUE, myFileName);
```

Comment: Didn't work.  keep in mind that everything works fine if a user is logged in.

Comment: ya well i see you have more likely another access problem... so is `winlogon` the parent process? did you allow your service to access the desktop?

Comment: a comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345274/memory-mapped-file-access-denied) mentions that a LocalService may not be able to create a MMF. try running the service as SYSTEM and also try by removing the AnonymousSid (why NullSid?), as this may also be overriden by a Deny rule

Comment: correct, `winlogon` is the parent. The service isn't set to interact with the desktop but shouldn't need to be.

Comment: some on SO and msdn mention that you may have to use an empty `new MemoryMappedFileSecurity()` (with no `AddAccessRule`), and one did only add WorldSid. if you don't need the other rules, try without all and once with only Everyone's WorldSid!

Comment: anon and null sid were both a product of thrashing around trying to figure out what needed to be granted access.  Removing the calls to `AddAccessRule` doesn't impact a users ability to run the screen saver.  nor does it allow it to run correctly without logging in.

Comment: it shows up, that `winlogon` is the parent process but it get's impersonated to the current logged on user, even when locking the desktop. in Win7 the logon screen has no screensaver... are you on xp?

Comment: Windows 7. See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/no-screen-saver-at-windows-7-welcomelog-in-screen/a437ee54-6f7f-48fd-8413-7338480948d8.  The whole point is to work around changes to how 'interact with desktop' worked in vista.

Comment: interestingly this spawns new processes `winlogon` with children `mpnotify`, `LogonUI` as SYSTEM and `scrnsave.scr` as LocalService. I'm sorry, can't help you. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this case ? I want to use share memory for transferring data between user session and login seasion. Named pipe works but I need faster communication. I set required permissions I can get data if it's running in service but in login screen it doesn't work