# How do I communicate between a server and a client on the same computer using memory mapped files?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shared-memory

I am really hoping someone can help me understand how memory mapped files work.  I've been doing a lot of research online, but sometimes it's just easier to ask for help.

I am creating a document creation system on a server I am running.  I would like to create a service which will serve the template files on demand to the client program (which is itself the service to the actual clients requesting a file).

I would like the template files to stay in memory so that the server doesn't have to access the hard drive each time a user requests a file.

I can't use piped connections because the files in question are too large.  I could use a socket-style connection, or break the file down into smaller pieces, but that seems like a less good solution than a memory mapped file, which seems to be designed to solve this exact problem, and seems to be the quickest way to share large files between two processes.

I couldn't get the memory mapped files to work until I changed the filename to be @"Global\" + filename (see code).  This worked for a while, but then it stopped working - but I have no clue what I changed. I got that idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301978/memory-mapped-file-and-win-service-cannot-find-file-created-by-server).  I think that whatever the "Global\" prepending does is related to the solution to my problem, since this seems to indicate that Windows memory is segmented in a similar way that the file system is formatted, and different processes may have different access levels.

Here is the code from the service:

```
public partial class TemplateDistributorService : ServiceBase
{
    protected ServiceHost host;
    public static Dictionary<string, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile> memFiles;
    public static Dictionary<string, int> fileSizes;

    public TemplateDistributorService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        memFiles = new Dictionary<string, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile>();
        fileSizes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var path in args)
        {
            string fileName = @"Global\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
            var sz = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;
            //all files must be less than 2GB for easier programming.  I don't anticipate
            //this being a problem, and if it does become one, we can up this to the max system file size (4 GB)
            if (sz <= System.Int32.MaxValue)
            {
                using (System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile mmf =
                    System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(fileName, 
                    sz, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    fileSizes[fileName] = System.Convert.ToInt32(sz);
                    using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                    {
                        using (var writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream))
                        {
                            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                            writer.Write(fileBytes);
                        }
                    }
                    memFiles[fileName] = mmf;
                }
            }
        }
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TemplateDistributor));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TemplateDistributorInterface),
          new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
          "net.pipe://localhost/PipedTemplateAccess");

        host.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        host.Close();
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface TemplateDistributorInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    int AddFile(string path, string fileName);

    [OperationContract]
    int FileSize(string fileName);
}

public class TemplateDistributor : TemplateDistributorInterface
{
    public int AddFile(string path, string fileName)
    {
        //prepending the filename with 'Global\' is really important.  Not sure why, but you can't access the memory mapped file without it
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301978/memory-mapped-file-and-win-service-cannot-find-file-created-by-server
        //string fileName = @"Global\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        if (TemplateDistributorService.memFiles.ContainsKey(fileName))
        {
            if (TemplateDistributorService.memFiles[fileName] != null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        var sz = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;
        if (sz > System.Int32.MaxValue)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        using (System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile mmf =
            System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(fileName, sz, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            TemplateDistributorService.fileSizes[fileName] = System.Convert.ToInt32(sz);
            using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream))
                {
                    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                    writer.Write(fileBytes);
                }
            }
            TemplateDistributorService.memFiles[fileName] = mmf;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public int FileSize(string fileName)
    {
        if (TemplateDistributorService.fileSizes.ContainsKey(fileName))
        {
            return TemplateDistributorService.fileSizes[fileName];
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the client-side code (Throws: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Core.dll" when I try to open the memory mapped file):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface TemplateDistributorInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    int AddFile(string path, string fileName);

    [OperationContract]
    int FileSize(string fileName);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestDocService();
    }

    static void TestDocService()
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\jack.geiger\Documents\BuschFTP.docx";

        ChannelFactory<TemplateDistributorInterface> streamPipeFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<TemplateDistributorInterface>(
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              new EndpointAddress(
                "net.pipe://localhost/PipedTemplateAccess"));
        TemplateDistributorInterface streamPipeProxy = streamPipeFactory.CreateChannel();
        string fileName = @"Global\Restricted\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        var f = streamPipeProxy.AddFile(path, fileName);
        f = streamPipeProxy.AddFile(path, fileName);

        //prepending the filename with 'Global\' is really important.  Not sure why, but you can't access the memory mapped file without it
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301978/memory-mapped-file-and-win-service-cannot-find-file-created-by-server
        //mmf is being created in service, but I can't find it here for some reason

        using (System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile mmf = 
            System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(
                fileName, 
                System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileRights.Read, 
                System.IO.HandleInheritability.None))
        {
            using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, 0, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (System.IO.BinaryReader binReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream))
                {
                    var fileSize = streamPipeProxy.FileSize(fileName);
                    var bts = binReader.ReadBytes(streamPipeProxy.FileSize(fileName));
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStr = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        memStr.Read(bts, 0, bts.Length);
                        memStr.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        using (WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.Create(memStr, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
                        {
                            template.MainDocumentPart.Document.RemoveAllChildren();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are your server really create "Global\somefile" without error ?

Comment: Yes, I have debugged that.  Also, as an additional sanity check I can check the value of "f" in the client application, and it returns 1 - indicating successful file creation (unless I debug twice without restarting the server, when it returns 0 - indicating the file already exists)

Comment: take `WinObj.exe` - when you *create* "memory mapped file" `Global\SomeName` the `\BaseNamedObjects\SomeName` *section* object must be created. and just before *open* `Global\BuschFTP.docx` - check - are `\BaseNamedObjects\BuschFTP.docx` *section* is exist ?

Comment: and your server must have `SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_PRIVILEGE` enabled - here explanation how `Global\` prefix work -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RbMm: When I create the \Global\BuschFTP memory mapped file in the server, I do not see it appear in the WinObj.exe program under the BaseNamedObjects folder.  However, the memory mapped file is created with no error in the service.  Here's what I see: http://imgur.com/a/7mtMk

Comment: Also, my service account is LocalSystem, which does have SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME privilege.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: if you really create `\Global\BuschFTP` it will be in `BaseNamedObjects` folder. so or you create and view it or you got error here. need exactly know this.

Comment: also you refresh/reexec `WinObj` after you create (if really create) `\Global\BuschFTP ` because `WinObj` enum all objects on start and not reflect new objects. at first you need exacly determinate - are you really create section(got not zero handle) and which name exactly

Comment: also for test you can try create `\Global\Restricted\BushFTP` *for test* - here 2 advantages - no need special privileges or rights for create object at this place (so everybody can do this(except anonymous logon)) and this folder usual empty - so more easy view files here. not forget exec WinObj *after* you create object. and check return handle

Comment: I refreshed the WinObj.exe program after creating the file, and it did not appear - even when I created the file using the filename "Global\Restricted\BuschFTP".  The service is still not throwing an error, and has a handle to the memory mapped file, I just can't access it from my testing program.

Comment: so you not created the file, or using another name. handle of file is != 0 ? I be easy can look name by handle, but don't know which public tool can do this

Comment: I modified the code from above so that when the client tells the server to create the memory mapped file, it also sends it the filename to use.  This is to ensure that the client and service aren't using two different names for the same file (although if I ever get this working, the service will be started when the computer is started, with a list of files to open, so that's why it wasn't like that above).  Once again, the service is creating the memory mapped file without an error, but I can't "access" the file in my other process.  I'll edit the code above to show how it's currently working.

Comment: if service is created (and not closed just after) named section - you can view it in WinObj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132839/discussion-between-jack-geiger-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was creating my memory mapped files inside a "Using" clause.  This was deleting the memory mapped file.  Thanks so much for your help @RbMm!  You helped me troubleshoot this and I don't think I had much of a shot solving this without your help.  Here's our chat transcript:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132839/discussion-between-jack-geiger-and-rbmm